# Application of the correspondence theorem for groups

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I'm attempting to solve the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a group with a normal subgroup $N$ of order $5$, such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$ on $4$ symbols. Prove that $|G|=120$, $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $20$, and exactly $4$ subgroups of order $15$ none of which is normal in $G$.

$|G|=120$ is a simple application of Lagrange's theorem. I'm struggling with the other parts. My first thought was to use the Sylow theorems, but it seems like they aren't very helpful here. My next thought is to use the correspondence theorem:

I understand that the general idea of the correspondence theorem is if $N\triangleleft G$ then there is a correspondence between the sets of subgroups $\{H\leq G:H\geq N\}$ and $\{K\leq G/N\}$. So applied here, since $S_4\cong G/N$, then subgroups in $G$ correspond to points (cosets) in $G/N$. Then taking the canonical homomorphism $\pi:G\rightarrow G/N$ by $g\mapsto gN$, we have that $\operatorname{ker}\pi=N$ so $|\operatorname{ker}\pi|=5$. Then I believe that $G$ having a normal subgroup of order $20$ follows from Lagrange's theorem and the first isomorphism theorem.

I'm looking for assistance primarily in resolving the last part of this problem, but also with building a stronger intuition for solving these types of problems.

Comment: Hints: to find a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $20$, find a normal subgroup of $G/N$ of order $4$, then "lift it up" using the correspondence. As for subgroups of $G$ of order $15$, show that they must contain $N$ and then use the correspondence to show that they correspond to groups of order $3$ in $G/N$ and then do the computation there...

Comment: @verret Okay I follow the argument for the normal subgroup of order $20$, but I'm a bit lost on the subgroups of order $15$. There is only $1$ subgroup of $S_4$ of order $3$ ($A_3$)...how does this give me $4$ subgroups in $G$? Also where does the (lack of) normality argument come from?

Comment: No, there is not just one subgroup of order $3$ in $S_4$. Hint: how many elements of order $3$ are there in $S_4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|S_4|=4!=24$. Thus, $|G/N|=24$. Then, by Lagrange's theorem, $|G/N|=[G:N]$ and so $|G|=|G/N|\cdot|N|=24\cdot5=120$.

Now, consider the subgroup $K=\{(),(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}\leq S_4\cong G/N$. Then $K\triangleleft G/N$, $|K|=4$, and $[G/N:K]=6$ (again by Lagrange's theorem). Thus, by the correspondence theorem, $K$ corresponds to a normal subgroup $H\triangleleft G$ such that $[G:H]=6$, and hence (by Lagrange's theorem) $|H|=120/6=20$.

Finally, since $G/N\cong S_4$ and $S_4$ has four subgroups of order $3$ ($\langle(1,2,3)\rangle,\langle(1,2,4)\rangle,\langle(2,3,4\rangle,\langle(1,3,4)\rangle$), none of which are normal in $S_4$, the desired result follows by application of the correspondence theorem.